# コミュニティが死にそうなんですがどうしたらいいでしょうか

Tags: ruby, redis

会社の [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) アプリケーションで、セッションストアとして [Redis Cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) を使っています。しかしクライアントソフトの [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) がクラスター機能に対応してなくて困ってました。セッション機能を自前で実装するハメになって今では技術的負債です。

そこで及ばずながらクラスター対応プルリクを決意して出したのですが、誰もレビューしてくれずに2ヶ月ほど放置されています。
https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/pull/716

このようなとき、政治的にどう動くのが最善なのでしょうか？ 私にはOSSで活躍しているような知人はおらず、私自身は底辺プログラマーで、Redis本体のCコードとかは読めません。

Forkは避けたいと考えてます。少なくはないスター数ですし、プログラムはみんなが使った方が鍛えられると思います。
https://redis.io/clients#ruby

Comment: もう少し待ってみてはいかがですか？１週間前に今時間がないとコメントをもらってい‌​ますよね。みんなさんボランティアで無料でメンテしているので。有償でサポートしてください、と‌​お願いするのも手かもしれませんね。リリー‌​ススケジュールとかマイルストーンとかがあ‌​るのかもしれないし、皆が使うライブラリほ‌​ど安定が求められますから、ぱっとマージす‌​るのは難しいと思います。当分ローカ‌​ルブランチを維持すればいいだけでは？マ‌​スターの取り込みを急ぐ理由は何でしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。待ってみます。ローカルブランチでも問題ないですが、そもそもRedis Clusterを使わない選択肢も出てきているので、やはり待ってみます。

Comment: 参考: 質問者さんの粘り強い活動と貢献、および反応してくださった contributor さんの出現により、はじめて PR が出てから 10 ヶ月ほど経った先日、PR がマージされました 

Comment: ありがとうございます。contributor さんには丁寧にレビューしていただき、すごくお世話になりました。私は英語が全然ダメでその点でもたくさん迷惑かけたと思うので反省してます。まだ正式にバージョンUPはされてませんが、早速会社のプロダクトで人柱になってみようと思います。

Comment: @UntyPocaPoca さん、もしよろしければ今回のご経験を[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)して頂けませんか？　これだけプラス投票の集まった質問ですし、回答が参考になる方はたくさんいらっしゃると思います :)

Comment: 書きましたー m(_ _)m

Answer (score 14, accepted):

セルフ回答ですみません。結果的にマージされましたので報告させていただきます。

私の当初のコードはRedis Cluster仕様的に考慮漏れが多く、テストケースも足りずに品質は最悪でしたがレビューアの方が丁寧に鋭く指摘してくれて最終的に実用に耐えうるレベルまで仕上げることができたかなと思います。

あとはリアルワールドで実際に使われて膿が出てくると思うので、今後どんなissueが出されるか引き続きチェックしていこうと思います。特に高トラフィックをさばくような大規模サービスで使われた場合にパフォーマンス面で問題が出そうな箇所とかが気になってます。

さて今回質問させていただいたコミュニティ停滞の問題ですが https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/752 でShopifyのRubyistたちがメンテナーに加わったことに救われた気がいたします。

またこの issue を上げたのが Sidekiq メンテーというのも救いの要因として大きい気がいたしました。

ShopifyのRubyistたちはRailsもメンテしてる方もおり、やはりOSSは評判というか「できる人たちができる人たちを知っている」構造なのかなと何となく感じました。

回答になってなくて恐縮ですが、今回のようにまずはコミュニティの現状について issue で聞いてみる、というのもありなのかもしれません。

ですがやはりエンジニアとして影響力がないとコミュニティを動かすのは難しそうだなというのが正直な感想です。私のような無名エンジニアは研鑽を積んで地道にOSS活動していくしかないのかなと思いました。